# Is M1 Macbook pro campatible with Lammps?

Tags: macos, apple-m1, lammps

I am trying to install lammps on my M1 Macbook Pro with homebrew. But everytime I execute the $brew install lammps$ command, it shows: bottle not available. I am wondering is it a compatibility issue? Or something simple that I am missing here? To note, I am really new to lammps.
Thanks, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This sounds more like a brew problem.  Try their forum. https://github.com/Homebrew/discussions/discussions

Comment: Probably at the time there were no bottles for arm64_big_sur. It works now, update brew and try again.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add Homebrew to the path with this command:

```
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH
```